# Electrical arc problem

Tags: electrical, wiring, switch, circuit-breaker, electrical-panel

I just changed a switch in my house and after I pushed it back in the box it arced and the breaker did not trip, so I rewired it. Now, the light is not getting any power but everything else on that circuit works.

Could there be a break in the wire somewhere in the wall?

Comment: We need more information. And the problem/situation needs to be explained more clearly; more methodically.

Comment: The problem's probably in the switch box in question -- if you can turn the breaker off, open it up, and give us good, clear photos of the innards, that'd be helpful, please

Answer (score 1):

The breaker didn't trip because it didn't need to.  A bad connection failed first.

Either in that junction box, or in the junction box before (next closer to the breaker box), you're going to find a scorched and arced wire on a screw or (far more likely) in a backstab.  This is why we don't like backstabs.

Arc fault breakers will protect you from fires starting from arcing backstabs.